# Linear algebra, writing operator matrix in different base

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

so i need to write matrix for this linear operator $A:R^2\rightarrow R^2$ $A\overrightarrow x= (2x_1+x_2)\overrightarrow e_1 + (-x_1 + 3x_2)\overrightarrow e_2$,matrix has to be written for $A^2$ operator in base $(\overrightarrow e_1 + \overrightarrow e_2,2\overrightarrow e_1-\overrightarrow e_2)$

Comment: Do you know how to write the matrix for $A$ in terms of this base? Once you have that, you could use matrix multiplication to find $A^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $A(e_1)=2e_1-e_2$ and $A(e_2)=e_1+3e_2$ (you obtain this by letting $x_{1}=1, x_{2}=0$, then letting $x_{1}=0, x_{2}=1$). So the matrix of $A$ with respect to the basis $e_1, e_2$ of $V$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 3\end{pmatrix}$. By the correspondence of linear maps and matrices, we have that the matrix of the linear map $A^2$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 3\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 3\end{pmatrix}$=$\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 5 \\ -5 & 8\end{pmatrix}$. But this is not yet with respect to the basis $e_1+e_2,2e_1-e_2$. The transformation matrix from the basis $e_1+e_2,2e_1-e_2$ to the basis $e_{1},e_{2}$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$. So the matrix of $A^2$ with respect to the basis $e_1+e_2,2e_1-e_2$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 5 \\ -5 & 8\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1/3 & 2/3 \\ 1/3 & -1/3\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 5 \\ -5 & 8\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$=$\begin{pmatrix} 14/3 & -35/3 \\ 5/3 & 19/3\end{pmatrix}$ $\square$